# Seting a color using color.xml - an string array

Tags: android

Hey I got this xml array:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="colors">        
        <item>BLUE</item>
        <item>CYAN</item>  
        <item>DARK_GRAY</item>
        <item>GRAY</item>
        <item>GREEN</item>
        <item>LIGHT_GRAY</item>
        <item>MAGENTA</item>
        <item>ORANGE</item>
        <item>PINK</item>
        <item>RED</item>
        <item>YELLOW</item>
        <item>WHITE</item> 
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

I was trying such simple method which obviously can't work:

```
public int[] getColorsArray(int i) {        
    int[] allColors = MyApplication.getContext().getResources().getIntArray(R.array.colors); //this is probably wrong
    int[] array = new int[i];

    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        array[j] = allColors[j]; //this is wrong
    }       

    return array;
}
```

}

Is there a way to use such xml array?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: actually I need colors array for a chart serie. I want to pick necessary ammount of colors from allColors array.

Comment: yeah well, getIntArray(R.array.colors) always gets 0; which is not weird as the xml array is an string array. I think I'm gonna do this another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I worked this out another way.

```
private int[][] allColors() {

int rgbArray[][] = { 
{3,48,208},       //blue    
{73,33,65},       //blue    
{63,92,202},      //blue    
{107,134,233}     //blue (yea, they are all different but I'm no woman) 
};

return rgbArray;
}

public int[] getColorsArray(int i) {        
    int[][] allColors = allColors();
    int[] array = new int[i];

    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        array[j] = Color.rgb(allColors[j][0], allColors[j][1], allColors[j][2]);

    }       

    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `in xml you have defined string-array but in program you are trying to get int-array`. Use `getStringArray` and check the results

```
String[] allColors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colors); //this is probably wrong
        String[] array = new String[allColors.length];

        for (int j = 0; j < allColors.length; j++) {
            array[j] = allColors[j]; //this is wrong

            System.out.println(j+"...j..."+allColors[j]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use 2 arrays, one string-arrays for the names and one int arrays for the colors values.